# Custom Dialog in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to close a dialog box after click on btnStart button. I don’t want to apply negative and positive button on dialog.?

```
  val context = this
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        // Seems ok to inflate view with null rootView
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, null)
        builder.setView(view)
        val btnStart=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_progress_dialog) as Button

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
          /*
          * I want close dialog box from here.
          *
          * */

        })


        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel) { dialog, p1 ->
            dialog.cancel()
        }



        builder.show()
```

Comment: val ad:AlertDialog= builder.show()
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
          /*
          * I want close dialog box from here.
          *
          * */
            ad.dismiss()
        })
Now its working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `create` to obtain dialog reference before showing it. That way it's easy to attach callback for dismissal:

```
// first create the dialog
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setView(view)
        .create()
// now we have a reference to dismiss it
btnStart.setOnClickListener {
    dialog.dismiss()
}
dialog.show()
```

Comment: Indentation in Kotlin is crucial (I never keep the builder reference in my code). If You don't want to one line your Builder call and want to use reference, you can use `builder.create()` to obtain the dialog.

Comment: val dialog : AlertDialog= builder.create()
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
          /*
          * I want close dialog box from here.
          *
          * */
            dialog.dismiss()

        })  I have tried this one but its not working.

Comment: did you replace last line with `dialog.show()` or created another dialog without listener with `builder.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Just set it to `null` if you want to hide it.

```
builder.setPositiveButton(null,null)
builder.setNegativeButton(null,null)
```